# handle home button pressing on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I need to handle home button pressing in my app.
When user presses home button in my `DetailedViewController` I need to trigger method that will `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`.
Help me please.
How could it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` method in you app delegate. It will catch the event. And then your can handle it as you need. For example, post notification using default notification center and get it in class where you need to do something.

Comment: Everything is clear. I that method using `self.navigationController.visibleViewController.nibName` I know what view controller is visible when user presses home button. But If my visible view controller's nib name is `DetailedViewController` I need to pop it (thats simple) but also I need to **cancel application's attempt to close my app**

Comment: There is no way you can cansel closing the app after Home button was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

What you want exactly? you want to get back to Home(root) or just want to get back to the previous page?

just try out with this code in which you get back to your starting or home controller

```
[self.navigationControler popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

As Павел Оганесян has described :

```
// post notification 
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
 {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" object:self];
}
```

Now in `DetailedViewController` .m file

```
// add observer
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) name:@"TestNotification"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // do the needful
}
```

Hope it helps you...